# Rejected because of DKIM check fail; alignment check fail

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

I am testing my mail server setup with this tool https://email-test.had.dnsops.gov/ and I am getting suspicious that the tool may not be working right.

From what I understand it reports that my alignment check fails. I do not understand what is failing, because **other online test tools state**:

- SPF: pass
- DKIM: pass
- DMARC: pass

This is the resulting report I get from the tool: (Note, the email address they provide in the report is not the one I used to generate the test. Somehow they got that wrong too.)

> This email contains the results of the email sent to the "test@email-test.had.dnsops.gov"
> test tool.  The test tool tries to obtain and validate SPF and DKIM on the sent message.
>
> The results are summarized below:
>
> SPF result: pass: pass: SPF found and SPF check for the sender at [my-IP-Address] passed.
>
> DKIM result: pass: DKIM key with selector "[my-selector]" found and successfully validated DKIM signature.
>
> DMARC result: DMARC RR found for sending domain.
>
> Ultimate disposition based on above: Rejected because of DKIM check fail; alignment check fail.

What do I need to do in order to align what is not aligned. It makes no sens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's referring to [DMARC Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC#Alignment). For DMARC to pass, you need either authorization via SPF on an aligned domain or else a valid signature via DKIM on an aligned domain.

Unless you've specified strict alignment (`adkim:s` or `aspf:s`), you're using the default relaxed mode for alignment, which means the organizational domain (aka paid-level domain, the thing you registered, residing right under the [public suffix](https://publicsuffix.org), like "foo.co.uk" rather than "mail.foo.co.uk"). If you are using strict alignment, the whole hostname (FQDN) must match to be aligned.

The domain used in your `From` header must be *aligned* with the domain used by DKIM (the `d=` value in the `DKIM-Signature` header) or with the domain used by SPF (the SMTP `mail from` command or the SMTP `helo` or `ehlo` name).

If you're sending with a header of `From: MeSo2 <meso2@example.com>` but the `DKIM-Signature` contains `d=meso2.provider.net`, DKIM is not aligned (example.com ≠ provider.net). If you also passed SPF but your SMTP conversation identified your host with `ehlo smtp.meso2.com` and sent the message as `mail from:<meso2@me.so2.com>`, SPF is not aligned (example.com ≠ meso2.com, example.com ≠ so2.com).

Comment: I have been testing my server using https://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim and with that test my DMARC passes. Could it be that the above .gov test is faulty for the DMARC portion?

Comment: That test is for DKIM and not for DMARC, so it won't be concerned with alignment. There's always the possibility that a test isn't thorough. If you edit your question to include details from the test result, we can take a look here.

Comment: DUH - Thank you! I must have misread that.